# How should I implement a unique priority field in my database?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm creating a database for event objects, each event has a priority (long) which is unique.  Objects with lower priority values are favored, newer object are initially assigned higher and higher priorities as the amount of object increases but the user can reassign priorities at will.

My question is should I use just _ID as the priority field?  I figure that way when I select them and put them into my ArrayList in Java my events will already be sorted by priority high to low and save me the trouble of having to search.  And depending on what algorithms SQLite actually uses selection by priority may be faster since it's also an index.  I'm new to SQL and this all seems well and good to me, but there might be some drawback that is plain to someone more experienced.

Also, I'm a bit unclear on how insertion into the middle of a table would work, probably use the update function to increment the row_ids above it but how do I make sure it increments them in the proper order? (so as to not tread on each other).

Something like this?:

```
UPDATE event_table SET priority = priority + 1 WHERE priority > ?
```

P.S:  I'm doing this on an Android 2.2 in SQLite 3

Comment: Hi, let us know if you narrowed down an approach. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think having a priority value of decimal datatype would make it easier to insert into the middle of the table. And not require you to do massive shifting when you're re-sorting.

Comment: I could do that, but it wouldn't help me keep the list sorted by priority.  I'd save time inserting, but spend more time searching.  When an event (let's say with priority 5) must execute I have to look at events with priority 0,1,2,3,4 in case they conflict.  I'd rather do a costly sort every time I insert than do a costly search every time I look for a conflict.  I will be searching more often.